# django + virtualenv = atomic upgrade - is it possible?

Tags: django, deployment, virtualenv, fabric, buildout

I have a Django project running within a virtualenv with no site-packages. When it comes to pushing my new changes to the server, I would like to create a new virtualenv directory, install my project and all its dependancies, then do a quick renaming of the two virtualenv directories ONLY if the new code deployed successfully.

All is great on paper, till the point you rename the virtualevn directory. Relocate option on virtualenv is not reliable as per its documentation.

How do you suggest upgrading my project ONLY if the new code is proven to be deployable.

Here are the steps:

```
# fab update_server to run the following:
cd /srv/myvenv # existing instance
cd ../
virtualenv myenv-1
source myenv-1/bin/activate
git co http://my.com/project
pip install -r project/req.txt
# all worked
mv myenv myenv-2; mv myenv-1 myenv
touch /path/proj.wsgi # have apache to reload us
```

The above is perfect, but renaming or relocating virtualenv is not reliable.

Upgrading the live site within myvenv takes time and may break the site too.

How would you do it? 
Buildout?

Comment: *Relocate option on virtualenv is not reliable as per its documentation* - sorry, can you explain this statement? What specifically isn't reliable? `--relocatable` sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: --relocatable is marked as experimental. I can't rely on it in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it with symlinks and completely separate release directories. Ie, a deployment involves cloning the entire project into a new directory, building the virtualenv inside that, then switching the "production" symlink to point at that directory.

My layout is basically

```
/var/www/myapp/
               uploads/
               tmp/
               releases/
                        001/myapp/
                        002/myapp/
                        003/myapp/
                                 ve/
                                 ...etc in each release directory...
               myapp # symlink to releases/003/myapp/
```

So, when I deploy to production, my deployment scripts rsync a completely fresh copy to `/var/www/myapp/releases/004/myapp/`, build a virtualenv in there, install all the packages into it, then

```
rm -f /var/www/myapp/myapp
ln -s /var/www/myapp/releases/004/myapp/ /var/www/myapp/myapp
```

My actual deployment script is a little more complicated as I also make sure to keep the previous release around and marked so if I notice that something is really broken, rolling back is just a matter of switching the symlink to point back at the previous one. (some extra work is also necessary to clean up old, unused releases if you are worried about the disk space).

Every external reference (in apache config files or wsgi files or whatever) point at libraries and binaries in the virtualenv as `/var/www/myapp/myapp/ve/`. I also shun the use of `source ve/bin/activate` and instead point at the full path in config files and I edit `manage.py` to use `#!ve/bin/python` so I can run commands with `./manage.py whatever` and it will always work without me having to remember if I've activated the right virtualenv.

Comment: Technically between 'rm' and 'ln' Apache could fail a request because WSGI script is missing. Slightly safer method is to have simple WSGI script outside of package and have it setup sys.path to somewhere in real location of project and have it import a module from there which sets up actual WSGI application. When updating, create new WSGI script file with new path in it and 'mv' it into place of existing one. The 'mv' command should be atomic as far as file system change.

Comment: Graham, that's a great idea. I'll see if I can work that into my process. I wasn't fooling myself into thinking that my approach is strictly atomic, just a large improvement over having the app broken for the duration of the virtualenv build.

Comment: Actually, the `rm` isn't necessary at all. You can use `ln -sf` to force the removal of the previous existing symlink.

Comment: now how do you roll back? I guess symlink would not happend unless all is good. But sometimes you something can fail right after symlink and I guess manually I can point the symlink back to the last known state. good solution, thx.

Comment: Thx Thraxil, I am wondering if uploads is used as the media or static directory. I guess it makes scenes to have the uploads intact after each release. For some reason my uploads endup in my static directory rather than the media directory in Django 1.3.1. Any thoughts? What do you use the tmp directory for?